# Get Custom Field Options List From Jira Via API

Tags: python-3.x, jira-rest-api

I would like to Get **Custom Field Options** List From Jira Via API (Python ver 3),

For example, Custom_field_13822 that represent "Severity" than I would like to get the options under it like, 1-low,3-Medium,5-High and etc... so i can use it.

I was able to do it with "issue_types" but i couldn't figure it out with the 
custom_fields,

my code for issue_type to get all the options under it:

```
issuetypes = jira.issue_types()
  for i in issuetypes:
   print (i)
```

i'm trying to get the same thing with custom fields like:

severity = issue.fields.customfield_13822

defecttype = issue.fields.customfield_11515

testingstream =  issue.fields.customfield_11518